# How to protect/encrypt the Nifi flow.xml.gz file?

Tags: apache-nifi

In order to prevent root to read the content of my flow.xml.gz, I would like to protect it from unwanted access.
Is it possible? how ?

Can Nifi compress this file with a password ?

Thanks in advance.

N.

Comment: passwords are already encrypted in flow.xml.gz. what is the reason to do that?

Comment: Only sensitive properties are encrypted in flow.xml.gz. Even so, the encryption key is stored in nifi.properties so accessible by root user...

Comment: hi. I would like to encrypt/protect the entire file.  Can Nifi compress this file with a password for example ?

Answer (score 0):

The root user can read/write all files on the system - you should instead focus on protecting root user access. As other comments state, the sensitive properties will be encrypted with an encryption key which is stored in nifi.properties. You can however configure alternative encryption mechanisms which do not require the encryption key to exist on the file system, such as Hashicorp Vault:
https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/07/20/apache-nifi-1-14-0-hashicorp-vault

Comment: Thanks for ur feedback rts404. I would want to protect the whole file flow.xml.gz from user root access. Encrypting the sensitive properties is not sufficient. Thanks!